# Issue with freeing an object

Tags: c, malloc

I'm currently attempting to learn the C side of C++.

I attempt to `malloc` a chunk of memory for a char array of `256` and then I assigned it a `char* "Hello World!"` but when I come to free the object I get an error.

Can anyone please explain to me the error.

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void* charVoidPointer = malloc( sizeof(char) * 256 ) ;
    charVoidPointer = "Hello World";

    std::cout << (char *)charVoidPointer;
    free (charVoidPointer);
}
```

Comment: There's one simple rule: **only free what you obtain from malloc**. IN your example, "Hello World" wasn't obtained from malloc.

Comment: You are trying to free static memory, the string "Hello World".  After you allocate the memory, you move the pointer to point to something else, creating a memory leak.

Comment: Now we know why `std::string` works much better! :-) The C library is full of stuff you are never going to use in C++ (`strpbrk`, anyone?). Don't bother with those until you *have to*.

Comment: You'd do well to learn the difference between C and C++.  They are NOT the same language.  malloc/free have NO place in C++ code, and std::cout has NO place in C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hello World" is statically allocated by the compiler.  It is part of the program and exists at some place addressable by the program; call it address 12.

charVoidPointer initially points to some place allocated for you by malloc; call it address 98.

charVoidPointer = "Hello ..." causes charVoidPointer to point to the data in your program; address 12.  You lose track of address 98 previously contained in charVoidPointer.

And you can't free memory not allocated by malloc.

To demonstrate more literally what I mean:

```
void* charVoidPointer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
printf("the address of the memory allocated for us: %p\n", charVoidPointer);
charVoidPointer = "Hello World";
printf("no longer the address allocated for us; free will fail: %p\n",
       charVoidPointer);
```

What you meant was:

```
strcpy(charVoidPointer, "Hello World");
```

Edit: Example of addressing memory for other types

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  // an array of 10 int
  int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

  // setting element 0 using memcpy (works for everything)
  int src = 2;
  memcpy(p+0, &src, sizeof(int));

  // setting element 1 using array subscripts.  correctly adjusts for
  // size of element BECAUSE p is an int*.  We would have to consider
  // the size of the underlying data if it were a void*.
  p[1] = 3;

  // again, the +1 math works because we've given the compiler 
  // information about the underlying type.  void* wouldn't have
  // the correct information and the p+1 wouldn't yield the result
  // you expect.
  printf("%d, %d\n", p[0], *(p+1));

  free (p);
}
```

Experiment; Change the type from int to long, or double, or some complex type.

Comment: Prefect explanation, but you have showed me how to assign a void* a char* to an object created by malloc but what about any other object ( like float, double or whateverclass).

Answer (score 2):

```
void* charVoidPointer = malloc( sizeof(char) * 256 ) ;
```

now `charVoidPointer` (weird name by the way - if you want chars, use `char *` and cast the pointer returned from malloc) points at a block of 256 characters. This block is uninitialized, so almost the only valid thing you can do is set them all to some value, or copy something in.

```
charVoidPointer = "Hello World";
```

now `charVoidPointer` points *instead* at a statically-allocated character array, and you've lost the address returned by malloc. There is no way to get it back, so this is a resource leak.

---

Your code should look something like:

```
char *charPointer = (char *)malloc(256);
strcpy(charPointer, "Hello World");
```

which *copies* the character array into your allocated block. Or, more concisely, just

```
char *charPointer = strdup("Hello World");
```

which will allocate a block just the right size *and* copy the string in. You still release the block with `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcpy(charVoidPointer, "Hello World");` because in your example you reassign your pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the pointer to the address of the string literal "Hello World", therefore the memory block you malloc'ed is leaked.

You should use

```
strcpy(charVoidPointer, "Hello World");
```

instead of the assignment operator.

Even better is to use `strncpy(charVoidPointer, "Hello World", 255);` to avoid overflowing the array you allocate.